# Java function overloading query

Tags: java, overloading

A extends B

```
public class Test {

public static void print(A obj) {
    System.out.println("print A");
}

public static void print(B obj) {
    System.out.println("print B");
}

public static void main(String [] args ) {  
    A x = new B();

    print(x);
}
```

}

Why it'll print "print A"? 
Why function overloading doesn't look up the real type of x in runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because overloading is not overriding. The compiler binds methods based on the declared types of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> Why function overloading doesn't look up the real type of `x` in runtime?

Because function overloading doesn't look up the real type of `x` at runtime, [by JLS #8.4.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9): "the number of actual arguments (and any explicit type arguments) and the compile-time types of the arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the method that will be invoked".